# How to access data from @Html.Raw object in jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I'm accessing `ViewBag` data using `JQuery` inside my view. it works fine like below.

```
var theData = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.DealDetails))';

console.log("ss ", theData);
```

and it gives output like below.[image]

now I want to access these data **ex: Month, price**. how can I access those.hope your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have array of objects. loop through array and access using object.key

small example provided here

```js
var data = [{price:23,month:2,other:"sfdsdf"},{price:11,month:12,other:"hello"},{price:212,month:1,other:"hello"}];


for(var i=0;i<data.length; i++){
  console.log("Price "+data[i].price);
  console.log("Month "+data[i].month);

}
```

Comment: it says `undefined`. I checked the typeof the `theData`, so it is a `string`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting back an array of objects so you can access it like this:

```
var month = theData[0].Month; // Month of first item
```

Or if you want to loop all items:

```
for (var i = 0; i < theData.length; i++) {
    alert(theData[i].Month);
    //Do something
}
```

**EDIT**

You can pass the data like this instead:

```
<script>
    var theData = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.DealDetail))
<script>
```

Comment: it says `undefined`. I checked the typeof the `theData`, so it is a `string`

Comment: @brian see my edit. Make sure `ViewBag.DealDetail` is not a string on the server side but they are objects.

Comment: @brian If `ViewBag.DealDetails` is a json string then you need to use `DeserializeObject` method. If it has objects, then `SerializeObject` should work.